# python - recursive call

Tags: python, scripting

I have a class model designed for a person class in python. where a person is a student and can have 0,1 or many advisors.A person can also have other attributes like name,school,year of graduation,classification he worked on,degree he obtained and so on.

I have set and get methods for each of these attributes in the class.
Ex. set_advisor(self,advisor) inserts advisor to the list of a student's advisors.
set_year(self,year) sets the year of graduation of student.

similarly get_advisor(self) returns the advisor of the student. and so on..

finally I populate the objects and name it as people.

if I want to get list of students who graduated in some year I just write

```
print [people[p].name for p in people if people[p].year="YEAR"]
```

Now, I want to write a query, say..list the students who graduated in some year and whose advisor trace back to say some "abc"...
eg dataset looks like this..

```
person a graduated in year 1990
person b graduated in year 1990
person c graduated in year 1991
person d graduated in year 1990
person a was advised by person e
person e was advised by person f
person f was advised by person g
person g was advised by person abc

person b was advised by person i
person i was advised by person abc

person c was advised by person abc

person d was advised by person h
person h was advised by person k
```

Now, I want to write a recursive query to track only those who graduated in 1990 and whose advisor trace back to abc.in the above case it should give me only a and b as result.

How do I go about this. I am having problems with the syntax and formulating the query.Like in the same terms as I formualted query above.
Can anybody help on this.

similarly..how do I write query for..say..
to get pairs of students who worked on some classification and graduated in same year and had their advisors also working on the same classification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a method on your class with something like:

```
has_advisor(self, advisor):
    if not self.advisor:
        return False
    elif advisor in self.advisor:
        return True
    else
        return self.advisor.has_advisor(advisor)
```

That would let you query things like:

```
e = people['e']
e_in_advisor_tree_and_grad_in_1990 = [p for p in people if p.has_advisor(e) and p.year == 1990]
```

This will get very expensive very quickly with large datasets, all of which are kept in memory at the same time.

Comment: in this case, self.advisor is likely to be a list of strings, so the recursive .has_advisor probably won't work, no?

Comment: looks promising. Would try as soon as I get back on it and update.

Comment: @Blair -- depends.  If self.advisor is list of strings, then we could substitute `people[adv_name] for adv_name in advisors`

Comment: The bigger problem is that this code actually assumes a single advisor or else self.advisor.has_advisor doesn't work -- because self.advisor is actually a list.  And once you start rewriting it for a list, the opportunities for repetitive, never-ending recursion abound, and there would need to be a mechanism for checking whether any given person had been checked already.